# Removing CrossOver Games from Unity Start panel

Tags: unity, crossover

I'm new to Ubuntu and  recently installed CrossOver Games Trial on Ubuntu 12.04, didn't like it, tried to uninstall it but simply refused to go away , so I just went on and deleted the folders in the File System.

Problem is that now there are 4 icons left on the Unity Start Panel under "installed applications", and I don´t know how to remove it. Actually, could anyone tell me how to delete any shortcut that is created on the Start Panel? Is there a way to do it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The shortcut that you are talking about are called `.desktop` files.  They are in one of two places.

`/usr/local/share/applications`

or

`home/.local/share/applications`   Note that the `.local` is a hidden file so you will need to show hidden files `Ctrl+h` to see them

Most likely the files are in the `usr/local` so you will need to use `sudo` to delete them.

When you delete these `.desktop` files they will no longer show up in your Dash under Installed applications but will still show up in the recent history until you open enough other programs to push them out.

Comment: glad I was able to help, Welcome to Ubuntu